# recreating the old youtube mobile player whit flash

Tags: html, flash, youtube, samsung-mobile

i have an old "smartphone", since youtube killed the old flash player (html5 video doesn't work and it has so few ram that i can't even load the full "the old net"
i never worked whit flash before (and i never really did anything similar)

the basic idea is to make an host a simple html page that ask you the id of the video, it download it, downscale it to 144p, convert in flash and send it to the phone
the problem is, i don't know how to use the buffering, so it work whit short videos, but when they're too long it fail to buffer everything when loading the page and break
i would like something like how youtube work (load piece by piece)
any ideas on how should i do this?

btw, the old phone is a samsung GT-S5260 whit samsung dolfin 2.0

Comment: **Opinion**: the result doesn't worth the effort. You need to figure out lots (seriously, lots, I mean it) of stuff, you need to have a server with **ffmpeg** or similar tool (which will probably cost something as it is not a basic web server). With the same amount of freelance work you would be able to afford a new smartphone.

Comment: i mean, i'm not doing this for really using the smartphone, it's for fun and because i like making stuff for those devices.
the biggest problem is the buffering thing, i managed to download and convert the file to swf flv1 video
i only want to see it, i don't care about anything else for now
and the phone is like 12/13 years old, lol

Comment: Ah : ) Then, you need a web server with any scripting capability (like PHP) that a) accepts youtube links as input, b) downloads the video body (no idea how, I have no experience with that), c) runs **ffmpeg** to convert the video into **FLV**, d) forms an HTML answer with prebuilt **FLV** player that accepts video urls via **FlashVars**.

Comment: well, i was using a javascript to download a video via ytdl-core, then downscale and convert it whit ffmpeg (i just a use a self local-hosted html and the scrip, then i'll work to combine the two)
the biggest problem, i don't have any idea how to work whit flash, never used it before, the only thing i know is the fact that's old

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my **AS3** is kinda rusty already, but I think it should work as the following.

First, you pass the video URL to the Flash application via **FlashVars**, it is a special HTML tag.

If you form HTML tags outright (figure urls and dimensions on your own):

```
<object width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="X" name="X" data="flvplayer.swf" >
    <param name="movie" value="flvplayer.swf">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="flvurl=movieurl.flv" />
    <embed width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="X" name="X" src="flvplayer.swf"
        allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
        allowFullScreen="true"
        quality="high"
        flashVars="flvurl=movieurl.flv"
        pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    ></embed>
</object>
```

Alternately, if you activate the **Flash** application through the **SWFObject**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {
        "flvurl=movieurl.flv"
    };
    var params = {
        allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain", 
        allowFullScreen: "true",
        wmode: "opaque",
        quality: "high",
        menu: "false"
    };
    var attributes = {};

    swfobject.embedSWF("flvplayer.swf", "X", "640", "480", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Ok. Next step, you need the means to build that **flvplayback.swf**. In order to do so, you need either **AIR SDK** or **Flex SDK** (optionally **FlashDevelop** tool because it made things so much easier back then, auto-downloaded SDKs too, but I have no idea if it works these days) or **Flash/Animate IDE**. I believe it is still possible to find some kind of tutorial like "*build my first Flash project*".

Then, the very application in question is rather simple one. The one below goes in a form of a single class, which should be the main class if you build thru **AIR/Flex SDK** or assigned as the document class if it is **Flash/Animate**.

```
package
{
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var playback:Video;
        
        public function Main()
        {
            // Being able to access the stage is important.
            if (stage) onStage(null);
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
        }
        
        private function onStage(e:Event):void
        {
            // The fact we are here means the stage is present and available.
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
            
            // Obtain the video URL.
            // That's why being able to access the stage was important.
            var flvurl:String = stage.loaderInfo.parameters["flvurl"];
            
            // If there's no URL provided, just stop.
            // Normally I'd put some visual alert here.
            if (!flvurl) return;
            
            // Set up stage a bit.
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.stageFocusRect = false;
            stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
            
            // Build and start the video player.
            var NC:NetConnection;
            var NS:NetStream;
            
            NC = new NetConnection;
            NC.connect(null);
            NS = new NetStream(NC);
            NS.play(flvurl);
            
            flvplayback = new Video;
            flvplayback.attachNetStream(NS);
            
            // Make it the size of the stage right away
            // then subscribe to any size changes.
            onResize(null);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);
            
            // Finally, attach the video player to the display list.
            addChild(flvplayback);
        }
        
        private function onResize(e:Event):void
        {
            flvplayback.width = stage.stageWidth;
            flvplayback.height = stage.stageHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot promise this would work right away, although I think it probably will. The idea is correct, the logic is straight, I just might forgot something or made some typos.